# Easier outline navigation in emacs

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I found this nifty little function for Org-mode:

```lisp
;;; Move to next heading with dedicated buffer preview
(defun ded/org-show-next-heading-tidily ()
  "Show next entry, keeping other entries closed."
  (if (save-excursion (end-of-line) (outline-invisible-p))
      (progn (org-show-entry) (show-children))
    (outline-next-heading)
    (unless (and (bolp) (org-on-heading-p))
      (org-up-heading-safe)
      (hide-subtree)
      (error "Boundary reached"))
    (org-overview)
    (org-reveal t)
    (org-show-entry)
    (show-children)))
```

It moves from headline to headline, and shows its direct content and children.
I liked the idea, but would rather it would show in a dedicated buffer, using `(org-tree-to-indirect-buffer)`.

I tried to do it like so:

```lisp
(defun ded/org-show-next-heading-test ()
  "Show next entry, keeping other entries closed."
  (if (save-excursion (end-of-line) (outline-invisible-p))
      (progn (org-show-entry) (org-tree-to-indirect-buffer))
    (outline-next-heading)
    (unless (and (bolp) (org-on-heading-p))
      (org-up-heading-safe)
      (hide-subtree)
      (error "Boundary reached"))
    (org-overview)
    (org-reveal t)
    (org-tree-to-indirect-buffer)
    (show-children)))
```

But then I have to double press the key - once it shows the entry in a dedicated buffer and secondly it still shows the entry.
I tried to remove the `progn` function, but then it didn't work entirely.

I'm not a lisp programmer, and I tried to play with it for an hour or so but to no avail, so I would love someone with some experience to help me sort this thing :)

Much obliged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up making my own, simple functions to navigate more easily:

```lisp
(defun forward-and-preview ()
    "Go to same level next heading and show preview in dedicated buffer"
    (hide-subtree)
    (org-speed-move-safe (quote outline-next-visible-heading))
    (show-children)
    (org-tree-to-indirect-buffer)
    )
(defun back-and-preview ()
    "Go to same level previous heading and show preview in dedicated buffer"
    (hide-subtree)
    (org-speed-move-safe (quote outline-previous-visible-heading))
    (show-children)
    (org-tree-to-indirect-buffer)
    )
(defun up-back-and-preview ()
    "Go to previous level heading and show preview in dedicated buffer"
    (org-speed-move-safe (quote outline-up-heading))
    (org-tree-to-indirect-buffer)
    (hide-subtree)
    )
(defun up-forward-and-preview ()
    "Go to previous level next heading and show preview in dedicated buffer"
    (org-speed-move-safe (quote outline-up-heading))
    (hide-subtree)
    (org-speed-move-safe (quote outline-next-visible-heading))
    (org-tree-to-indirect-buffer)
    )
(defun inside-and-preview ()
    "Go to next level heading and show preview in dedicated buffer"
    (org-speed-move-safe (quote outline-next-visible-heading))
    (show-children)
    (org-tree-to-indirect-buffer)
    )
(add-to-list 'org-speed-commands-user '("l" inside-and-preview))
(add-to-list 'org-speed-commands-user '("j" forward-and-preview))
(add-to-list 'org-speed-commands-user '("k" back-and-preview))
(add-to-list 'org-speed-commands-user '("J" up-forward-and-preview))
(add-to-list 'org-speed-commands-user '("K" up-back-and-preview))
```

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure what you want but as far as I can understand you should call `org-tree-to-indirect-buffer` at the end:

```lisp
;;; Move to next heading with dedicated buffer preview
(defun ded/org-show-next-heading-tidily ()
  "Show next entry, keeping other entries closed."
  (if (save-excursion (end-of-line) (outline-invisible-p))
      (progn (org-show-entry) (show-children))
    (outline-next-heading)
    (unless (and (bolp) (org-on-heading-p))
      (org-up-heading-safe)
      (hide-subtree)
      (error "Boundary reached"))
    (org-overview)
    (org-reveal t)
    (org-show-entry)
    (show-children)
    (org-tree-to-indirect-buffer)))
```

If it's not what you want then could you please give more details.

Comment: It's almost what I want. Now I don't have to press twice to move to the next headline. The one thing I miss is not having the entry's content shown in the current buffer, but only in the dedicated buffer...(show only headlines and sub-headlines, and note "pure" content). Hope I clarified.